# Maintaining different stock levels of the same product

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, stock

I purchased this Magento Template which is using 1.7.0.0 and got stuck since i cant add clothing stuff because those needs to be sold in different colours + different sizes etc , but the issue is maintaing different  stock levels for each product

Kindly Consider this Example :

I got 10 T Shirts

They are 3 different Sizes

3 T shits Small , 2 Medium &  5 Large

Under Small - I got 2 red & 1 blue ( altogether 3 )

Under Medium - I got 1 red & 1 blue ( altogether 2 )

Under Large - I got 2 red & 3 blue ( altogether 5 )

Ok here is the issue :

How i am going to maintain stock level accurately , even though the Total is 10 , they are in different sizes & different colours

Under Normal Circumstances , if a customer order 10 in small with BLUE colour , i will be in big trouble

What is your solution ?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make the group of attributes for this type of product variation

Second, you have to create a global attribute (of the type dropdown and that can make configurable products)

Third, than link this attribute to the attribute set

Forth, create the configurable product

Fifth, edit the configurable product and go to the tab associated products and quick create you variations (simple products)

Here follows a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzNAnUtvQhs

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create a configurable product with all combinations as simple product. Then, you can manage the stock of the underlying simple products.